# how to decipher this 8 digit timestamp?

Tags: datetime, time, timestamp, unix-timestamp, sql-timestamp

I am retrieving data of certain events from an API. And I came across this super strange 8 digit number (some sort of timestamp most probably) but I can not make any sense of what those numbers are. The API documentation wasn't kind enough to tell details of this particular `duration` field.

Here is the portion of API response:

```json
            "created_date": "2021-10-06T15:28:56.104897",
            "custom_event_name": null,
            "dev_fee_payment_event": null,
            "duration": "15541075",
            "ending_price": "2690000000000000000",
            "event_type": "created",
```

What I have tested so far, and have concluded is that it CAN NOT be the:

1. UNIX epoch
2. Number of seconds
3. Number of milli/micro seconds.

This is an [example full json response](https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/events?asset_contract_address=0xba30e5f9bb24caa003e9f2f0497ad287fdf95623&token_id=7179&event_type=created&only_opensea=false&offset=0&limit=1). And this is the [API documentation link](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/asset-object)

Any idea what this `duration` field could possibly signify?

Comment: What duration would you typically expect?

Comment: mostly 155XXXXX - 157XXXXX
some other examples are 15541075, 15724892, 15658466, 15722036, 15724891

Comment: most probably it is a recorded interval in some format starting from the `created_date`

Comment: Sorry I meant what you'd consider a reasonable duration, like an hour, a day, or a week. Maybe you can also find a clue on their SDK's code on github?

Comment: Few hours or even a day or 2 would be a reasonable duration time. And nice suggestion! I will surely check out the GitHub code

Comment: It’s funny that the numbers are so close. If milliseconds they’d be in the range of 4 hours and 19 to 23 minutes, no great variation, so we’re probably missing something essential. If centiseconds (100ths of a second) the range would be 1 day and 19 to 20 hours.

Comment: you will see they follow a very close linear pattern for seconds too. that linear pattern is exactly what makes me wonder more about this variable

Comment: Very interesting. If you could present that pattern in the question, maybe we can figure something out. (For example, what is the accompanying  seconds value for each of your example durations, 15541075, 15724892, 15658466, 15722036, 15724891?)

Comment: have you ever found the solution?

Comment: Update: never found a solution